# Updated documentation to interface R and Fusion Tables

Tags: r, rest, google-api, google-fusion-tables

can anyone provide updated documentation for interfacing R with Fusion Tables  1.0 API?

Old package:
http://andrei.lopatenko.com/rstat/fusion-tables.R

I am trying to understand how to use an API key to make SQL calls to Fusion Tables. After succesfully connecting with client login, running the code below returns "Forbidden".

```
ft.executestatement <- function(auth, statement) {
  url = "https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/query"
  params = list( sql = statement, key = "XXXXXXX")
  connection.string = paste("GoogleLogin auth=", auth, sep="")
  opts = list( httpheader = c("Authorization" = connection.string))
  result = postForm(uri = url, .params = params, .opts = opts) 
  if (length(grep("<HTML>\n<HEAD>\n<TITLE>Parse error", result, ignore.case = TRUE))) {
  stop(paste("incorrect sql statement:", statement)) 
}
return (result)  
}
```

Any direction is much appreciated.